# PostgreSQL View Creating Huge Temp File

Tags: postgresql, view

I have 3 rather simple tables in Postgres that record which IDs were valid for each business date going back several years.  The three tables represent 3 sources that record activity from these IDs.  I can't give you the entire table, but imagine:

```
    Date          ID
    2000-01-02    1
    2000-01-02    2
    2000-01-02    3
    2000-01-02    4
    . . .
    2018-01-02    49997
    2018-01-02    49998
    2018-01-02    49999
    2018-01-02    50000
```

So each table has daily data with potentially tens of thousands of IDs.  Not all IDs show up on all days in all tables, so all I want is a view that gives me the master list of any ID that shows up on any of the tables on any of the days.  Simple:

```
    create view all_ids as 
    select distinct * from table1 union 
    select distinct *  from table2 union
    select distinct * from table3;
```

The view is created without any problem but it proves impossible to query.  If I want to see what days a single id shows up on, I would write:

```
    select * from all_ids where id=37;
```

The problem is that when Postgres runs this query, it first attempts to create a huge temporary table that is the union of the 3 tables.  This, unfortunately, exceeds the temp_file_limit (5767168kB), and as I am not an admin, I cannot change the temp_file_limit.  Regardless, this seems to contradict my understanding of how views even work.  Please note: I can query an id or list of ids from any of the individual tables just fine.

I can write this as a function that I can pass specific IDs, but again, I believe that the view itself is supposed to handle this by returning just what I am asking for rather than creating the universe of data in memory first and then selecting from it.

Other relevant information is that we're using an old version of Postgres, 9.2.23.  I am thinking there is something wrong about how it is handling views.  The answer may be to bug out admin to upgrade this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just added information about the Postgres version.  We are running 9.2.23, quite an old version, that does not support materialized views.  I have tried to create a table directly rather than a view, and this process also uses the temp file (and runs out of space).  This leads me to believe that a materialized view would also be using a temp file and find itself out of space.  But maybe things have been drastically improved in newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is `materialized views`. I will just quote from the docs::

`CREATE VIEW defines a view of a query. The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query.`

The view that you have created `all_ids`, like you said, gets `re-created` every time this view is referenced.

**Edit** applies to Postgres 9.3+